# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am using a FutureBuilder with two downloads and putting each index to a list to load/show them in my app. With null safety there is an error:

The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

How can i solve this error in the snapshot (snapshot.data[0])? Thanks for help.

[image]

```
          FutureBuilder(
            future: Future.wait([downloadsuche(), downloadsuchvorschlag()]),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                //List<AdressSuche> adresse = snapshot.data;

                List<AdressSuche> adresse = snapshot.data[0];
                List<AdressSuche> sv1 = snapshot.data[1];

                return IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {
                    showSearch(context: context, delegate: DataSearch(adresse, sv1));
                  },
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {});
                //return RefreshIndicator(onRefresh: _refreshdata, child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
              }
              return IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {});
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```dart
List<AdressSuche> adresse = snapshot.data[0];
List<AdressSuche> sv1 = snapshot.data[1];
```

with

```dart
var adresse = (snapshot.data as List)[0] as List<AdressSuche>;
var sv1 = (snapshot.data as List)[1] as List<AdressSuche>;
```

Comment: why not just `snapshot.data![0]`?

Comment: @PatrickMahomes `snapshot.data!` returns an `Object` and you can't use `[]` operator on it.

Comment: thanks. no error from code. i have to test the function after compiling. but still a lot of null safety problems to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
List<AdressSuche> adresse = snapshot.data[0];
List<AdressSuche> sv1 = snapshot.data[1];
```

With

```
var list = snapshot.data! as List;

List<dynamic> adresse = list[0];
List<dynamic> sv1 = list[1];
```

Comment: It won't work because `snapshot.data` returns `Object?` and you can't use `[]` operator on an `Object` with Dart null safety.

Comment: Sorry! @copsOnRoad, I thought the problem was only with the null safety.
I edited my answer so please check it

Comment: thanks. no error from code. i have to test the function after compiling. but still a lot of null safety problems to solve.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I used your answer as a reference (because I'm not so good with writing) but I added the null safety handling to it because it was the problem that had been provided by the question.

BTW, You also didn't upvote my answer hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Simply add '!' after snapshot.data as snapshot.data may be null.

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: Future.wait([downloadsuche(), downloadsuchvorschlag()]),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                //List<AdressSuche> adresse = snapshot.data!;

                List<AdressSuche> adresse = snapshot.data![0]; //add '!' over here
                List<AdressSuche> sv1 = snapshot.data![1];  // and here

                return IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {
                    showSearch(context: context, delegate: DataSearch(adresse, sv1));
                  },
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {});
                //return RefreshIndicator(onRefresh: _refreshdata, child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
              }
              return IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {});
            },
          ),
```

Comment: already tried. result: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.